# How do VPN services bypass same IP connection limit?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I tried spinning up my own VPN instance using OpenVPN, through protocols like PPTP and L2TP, but it turns out that I can only connect one device to the VPN from the same wifi network. So if I have two devices connected to the same wifi network, only one can be connected to the VPN server.

However, popular VPN providers all seem to have a 3 device connection limit, even from the same wifi network. How are they able to get around this limitation?

Comment: OpenVPN, PPTP, and L2TP have nothing to do with each other. Which are you using? Many routers have problems supporting multiple PPTP connections, but OpenVPN (which is a completely different protocol) has no such restrictions.

Comment: @EEAA ah ok, so this limitation only applies to PPTP servers?

Comment: That's correct.